# Email configuration Install Flow in iOS 12.1.1 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, configuration, profile, beta

I am testing `.emailconfig` install on the new iOS 12.1.1 beta3. The profile gets downloaded from the webpage. But then, it shows "Profile Downloaded Install downloaded profile from settings". Previously, it used to redirect to "Settings=>General=>Profiles" as soon as we click allow profile installation on web-page.Now, the User has to manually go to this point. Does anyone know if it is a bug on Apple side? or If it is going to be like this from now on? Is there a documentation on this change? Is there a way to work-around like install downloaded profile in background or maybe route user to "Settings=>General=>Profiles" page? I don't think many iPhone Users know about configuration profiles and where they live. This could greatly impact Apps/ Services relying on configuration profiles. Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a bug. It’s a recent change, most likely for security reasons to prevents users from unknowingly installing one of these profiles.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/9xetoj/question_step_to_install_the_configuration/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, today Apple released it on iOS 12.2.

> When you download a configuration profile from a website or an email
>   message in iOS 12.2 or later, including profiles to enroll in Mobile
>   Device Management, you need to go to the Settings app to install it.

See here: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT209435